# How can I evaluate the matrix in x0=(0,0) if the first variable x doesn't appear?

Tags: matlab

I made a program for the "Newton-Raphson method for vectorial function".

Assume I have the function `f(x,y)=(x-y,x+y^2)`. The Jacobian matrix is `[1,-1;1,2*y]`. Then I put `r=symvar(jacobian)` and to evaluate it, I use `subs(jacobian,r,x0)`.

How can I evaluate the matrix in `x0=(0,0)` if the first variable `x` doesn't appear?

Comment: @lax "Newton-Raphson method for vectorial function" is *not* code. Please don't mark it up as such.

Answer (score 2):

I'm scratching my head over why you are trying to complicate your (and my) life.

1. You don't need to calculate the jacobian: Matlab does it for you with the `jacobian` function (first you must remove the jacobian variable instance from your workspace)

   ```
   jak = jacobian(f);
   ```
2. Next, you can use the `eval` function to do your bidding:

   ```
   x = 0, y = 0;
   eval(jak)

   ans =

     1.00         -1.00
     1.00             0
   ```

Answer (score 1):

If x does not appear in the expression for the jacobian, it means its value does not impact the resulting jacobian.

If your question is how to evaluate:

```
[1,-1;1,2*y]
```

when x and y are both equal to 0, the answer is very simple:

```
[1,-1;1,2*0]
```

Which boils down to:

```
[1,-1
 1, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

As the other users already suggested, you may follow this alternative solution

```
syms x y
jacobian([x - y,x + y.^2])
```

For evaluating in `x = 0` just type in

```
subs(jacobian([x - y,x + y.^2]),0)
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: @user1994492: you might evaluate the idea of accepting one of the proposed answer to your question.